# unsupported operand types in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

```
def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'datetime.timedelta
```

Comment: Try using `datetime` as: `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: Apparently `timezone.now()` is returning a function. `timezone` isn't a module from the standard library, though, so I can't verify that readily.